# Dynamic view panel column header formatting in xpages

Tags: view, xpages, javabeans

I'm using dynamic view panel in an xpages application, and I'm using a customizer bean provided by Jesse Gallagher (https://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=dynamicviewcustomizer) to format the panel. In the code there is the treatment to render the column header according to the properties defined in the Notes view, however the properties are not being passed, since the columns in the notes view are bold and this is not being reflected in the dynamic view panel. Can someone help me to verify what is wrong?

Follow the DXL view and xpages code

```
    <!DOCTYPE database SYSTEM "C:\Notes9\xmlschemas/domino_9_0_1.dtd">

    -<database title="Gestão de despesas de água e energia de agências" allowbackgroundagents="false" path="CN=Snmb24/O=Mercantil do Brasil!!GestaoAguaEnergia.nsf" replicaid="8325802D005D8C64" maintenanceversion="1.4" version="9.0" xmlns="http://www.lotus.com/dxl">


    -<databaseinfo numberofdocuments="189" percentused="87.4150815217391" diskspace="6029312" odsversion="43" dbid="8325802D005D8C64">


    -<datamodified>

    <datetime dst="true">20170112T164849,51-02</datetime>

    </datamodified>


    -<designmodified>

    <datetime dst="true">20170112T165138,37-02</datetime>

    </designmodified>

    </databaseinfo>


    -<fulltextsettings breakat="wordssentencesparagraphs" includeencryptedfields="false" includeattachments="true" update="immediate" size="1922029">


    -<lastindexed>

    <datetime>20170112T191311,61+00</datetime>

    </lastindexed>

    </fulltextsettings>


    -<launchsettings>

    <noteslaunch whenopened="openaboutdocument"/>

    <weblaunch whenopened="openxpage" xpage="GastosPorAgência.xsp"/>

    </launchsettings>


    -<view noemptycategories="true" initialbuildrestricted="false" uniquekeys="false" marginbgcolor="white" marginwidth="0px" hidemarginborder="false" allowcustomizations="true" allownewdocuments="false" evaluateactions="false" boldunreadrows="false" headerbgcolor="white" totalscolor="black" bgcolor="white" haslinkcolumn="true" rowspacing="1" headerlinecount="1" rowlinecount="1" unreadcolor="black" showhierarchies="false" extendlastcolumn="false" shrinkrows="false" showmargin="true" showresponsehierarchy="true" opencollapsed="false" headers="beveled" onrefresh="displayindicator" onopengoto="lastopened" unreadmarks="none" designerversion="8.5.3" publicaccess="false" noreplace="true" showinmenu="false" alias="VGastosAgencia" name="(Gastos por agência)">


    -<noteinfo sequence="39" unid="219D8F4FA6912B1D8325802D0069918A" noteid="19e">


    -<created>

    <datetime>20160913T161305,38-03</datetime>

    </created>


    -<modified>

    <datetime dst="true">20170112T145220,92-02</datetime>

    </modified>


    -<revised>

    <datetime dst="true">20170112T145220,91-02</datetime>

    </revised>


    -<lastaccessed>

    <datetime dst="true">20170112T145220,92-02</datetime>

    </lastaccessed>


    -<addedtofile>

    <datetime>20160913T161305,38-03</datetime>

    </addedtofile>

    </noteinfo>


    -<updatedby>

    <name>CN=Marcus Loza/O=Mercantil do Brasil</name>

    </updatedby>


    -<wassignedby>

    <name>CN=Marcus Loza/O=Mercantil do Brasil</name>

    </wassignedby>


    -<code event="selection">

    <formula>listaStatus:="Enviado para agência":"Enviado para gestor":"Devolvido para agência":"Enviado para contabilidade":"Ciente":"Novo"; SELECT form="GastoEnergiaAgua"& @IsMember(status;listaStatus)</formula>

    </code>


    -<column twisties="true" categorized="true" showaslinks="false" sortnocase="true" sortnoaccent="true" separatemultiplevalues="true" resizable="true" width="28.7500" itemname="agencia" hidedetailrows="false" sort="ascending">


    -<columnheader>

    <font size="9pt" style="bold"/>

    </columnheader>

    </column>


    -<column showaslinks="true" sortnocase="true" sortnoaccent="false" separatemultiplevalues="false" resizable="true" width="23.3750" itemname="status" hidedetailrows="false" sort="ascending">

    <font color="navy"/>


    -<columnheader title="Status">

    <font size="9pt" style="bold"/>

    </columnheader>

    </column>


    -<column showaslinks="false" sortnocase="true" sortnoaccent="false" separatemultiplevalues="false" resizable="true" width="10" itemname="$6" hidedetailrows="false" showasicons="true">


    -<columnheader>

    <font size="9pt" style="bold"/>

    </columnheader>


    -<code event="value">

    <formula>listaStatus:="Enviado para agência":"Enviado para gestor":"Devolvido para agência":"Enviado para contabilidade":"Novo"; dif:=dt_debito-@Today; @If(dif<0;"icons/cancel_or_decline/status_red.gif";"")</formula>

    </code>

    </column>


    -<column showaslinks="false" sortnocase="true" sortnoaccent="false" separatemultiplevalues="false" resizable="true" width="10" itemname="dt_debito" hidedetailrows="false">


    -<columnheader title="Data débito">

    <font size="9pt" style="bold"/>

    </columnheader>

    <datetimeformat preference="custom" timeformat24="true" timeseparator=":" dateseparator3="/" dateseparator2="/" dateseparator1=" " weekdayformat="shortname" yearformat="fourdigityear" monthformat="twodigitmonth" dayformat="twodigitday" dateformat="weekdaydaymonthyear" zone="never" time="hourminutesecond" fourdigityearfor21stcentury="true" date="yearmonthday" show="date"/>

    <numberformat bytes="false" percent="false" parens="false" punctuated="false" format="general"/>

    </column>


    -<column showaslinks="false" sortnocase="true" sortnoaccent="false" separatemultiplevalues="false" resizable="true" width="10" itemname="tipo_gasto" hidedetailrows="false">


    -<columnheader title="Gasto">

    <font size="9pt" style="bold"/>

    </columnheader>

    </column>


    -<column showaslinks="false" sortnocase="true" sortnoaccent="false" separatemultiplevalues="false" resizable="true" width="10" itemname="valor" hidedetailrows="false">


    -<columnheader title="Valor">

    <font size="9pt" style="bold"/>

    </columnheader>

    <numberformat preference="custom" bytes="false" percent="false" parens="false" punctuated="true" format="fixed" usecustomsym="false" currencysym="R$" currencysymtype="custom" thousandssep="." decimalsym="," digits="2"/>

    </column>


    -<column showaslinks="false" sortnocase="true" sortnoaccent="false" separatemultiplevalues="false" resizable="true" width="10" itemname="consumo" hidedetailrows="false">


    -<columnheader title="Consumo">

    <font size="9pt" style="bold"/>

    </columnheader>

    </column>


    -<item name="$FormulaTV">

    <text/>

    </item>

    </view>
```

Xpages code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view
    xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom"
    xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
    <xp:this.afterPageLoad><![CDATA[#{javascript:sessionScope.viewPage = view.getPageName();}]]></xp:this.afterPageLoad>
    <xp:this.resources>
        <xp:styleSheet href="/layout.css"></xp:styleSheet>
    </xp:this.resources>

    <xp:this.beforePageLoad><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewStateBean.restoreState = true;
var roles = context.getUser().getRoles();
sessionScope.userRoles = roles;
var st_novo=["Rascunho","Novo"];
var st_Contratos=["Enviado para gestor"];
var st_Contabilidade=["Enviado para contabilidade"];
var st_agencia=["Devolvido para agência","Enviado para agência"];

applicationScope.Contratos=st_Contratos;
applicationScope.Contabilidade=st_Contabilidade;
applicationScope.Agencia=st_agencia;
applicationScope.Novo=st_novo





}]]></xp:this.beforePageLoad>
    <xc:cc_layout navigationPath="/Gastos/PorAgência">
        <xp:this.facets>
            <xp:panel
                xp:key="facetMiddle"
                id="panelMainContent">
                <xe:dynamicViewPanel
                    id="dynamicViewPanel1"
                    showColumnHeader="true"
                    width="100%"
                    rows="25"
                    var="viewEntry"
                    customizerBean="mcl.reports.DynamicViewCustomizer">
                    <xp:this.facets>
                        <xe:pagerSizes
                            id="pagerSizes1"
                            xp:key="footerPager"
                            for="dynamicViewPanel1">
                        </xe:pagerSizes>
                        <xp:pager
                            layout="Previous Group Next"
                            partialRefresh="true"
                            id="pager1"
                            xp:key="headerPager"
                            for="dynamicViewPanel1">
                        </xp:pager>
                        <xe:pagerExpand
                            id="pagerExpand1"
                            xp:key="viewTitle"
                            for="dynamicViewPanel1">
                        </xe:pagerExpand>
                    </xp:this.facets>
                    <xe:this.data>
                        <xp:dominoView
                            var="view1"
                            viewName="VGastosAgencia">
                        </xp:dominoView>
                    </xe:this.data>
                </xe:dynamicViewPanel>
                <xe:pagerSaveState
                    id="pagerSaveState1"
                    for="dynamicViewPanel1"
                    partialRefresh="true">
                </xe:pagerSaveState></xp:panel>
            <xc:cc_nav_principal xp:key="facetLeft"></xc:cc_nav_principal>
        </xp:this.facets>
    </xc:cc_layout>
</xp:view>
```

Grateful!

Marcus

Comment: Edit your question and add your code. Hard to verify something one can't see

Comment: As I said I have a dynamic view panel based on a view and the bean customizer code is the same as the link posted above in the description of the problem. What code would you like me to put here?

Comment: Your XPage, your view dxl

Comment: The code were included.

Comment: Did you try to have the panel on its own page (for testing)? Does it work then?

Comment: I put the dynamic view panel on a page and the problem persisted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was override the oneui css for the dynamic view panel column headers with the tag below.

```
.xspPanelViewColumnHeader
{
Font-weight: bold
}
```

Comment: Can you achieve fixed headers using a customizer bean?

Comment: I have not tried, because of the bean customizer I have, the columns headers are created from view notes headers. But I think with some adjustments in the customizer bean gives to have fixed headers, however in this case you lose some of the versatility of the bean.